# Structs with 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm not very good at C yet so I have some questions.

I have two of the following structs:

```
typedef struct line_elems line;
typedef struct cache_handler *cache;

struct line_elems { // we don't care about valid/block bits in our simulator
  int tag;
  int freq; // for LRU principle
};

struct cache_handler {
  int hit;
  int miss;
  int evict;
  line **lines; // 2d array for sets
};
```

In initialized the cache by:

```
cache make_cache(int s, int E) {
  int i;
  cache new = malloc(sizeof(struct cache_handler));
  new->hit = 0;
  new->miss = 0;
  new->evict = 0;
  line **new_line = malloc((1 << s) * sizeof(*new_line));
  for(i = 0; i < (1 << s); i++)
    new_line[i] = malloc(E * sizeof(struct line_elems));

  new->lines = new_line;
  return new;
}
```

Now, I want to create a system to search through a single row in the 2d array:

```
int search_lines(line *lines, int E, int tag, int frequency) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < E; i++) {
    //continue here
  }
}
```

I'm a little confused on what exactly I'm supposed to input into my search_lines function.
If I input: `search_lines(cache->lines[0], E=5, tag=5, frequency=5)` Will it do what I'm expecting? That is, will it search through a single line in my 2d array? I feel that `cache->lines[0]` is not the same as a `(line*)`.
What is the difference between a `cache->lines` and a `cache->lines[0]`? This is confusing me because does the `->` operator implicitly perform one level of dereferencing?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't call the cache 'new'. It's a keyword in C++, and it's just going to introduce a world of pain if you ever try to compile your code in C++.

Comment: new is a terrible variable name to begin with (you should always use descriptive names), but altering your code to be C++ compliant when programming in C is a terrible reasoning. I would assume you would use C++ if you cared about ever compiling your code as it.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that, going to change that in all my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`"What is the difference between a cache->lines and a cache->lines[0]?"`*

`cache->lines` is `struct line_elems**` which is your 2D array. Actually it is a pointer to first element of your 2D array. Operator `->` is used because `cache` is `cache_handler*` = you are accessing members of `struct cache_handler` with it.

`cache->lines[0]` is `struct line_elems*` which is 1D array at index 0 = it is also a pointer to first element of your 2D array.

Note that freeing of this memory should have opposite order than your allocation:

```
line **new_line = malloc((1 << s) * sizeof(*new_line));
for(i = 0; i < (1 << s); i++)
    new_line[i] = malloc(E * sizeof(struct line_elems));
```

you free each `new_line[i]` first and after that you free `new_line` itself:

```
for(i = 0; i < (1 << s); i++)
    free(new_line[i]);
free(new_line);
```

Comment: So now, if I were to actually search through the line, would I put something like "lines[i].tag=1234"? Like would that access the specific field in each line?

Comment: Sorry, last question, I'm trying to create a 'free' function, and I basically have the following line that frees my cache: free(new_cache->lines[i][j]); When I try this, however, it doesn't work. (Note, i, j are in a nested for loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped. I think I'm getting the hang of this pointer stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

The `->` operator is not dereferencing `lines`, it is dereferencing `cache`. This is necessary because `cache` is also a pointer (created by a call to `malloc`.) Thus, it must be dereferenced before accessing any of its fields.

`cache->lines` is a `line **`

`cache->lines[0]` is a `line *`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reference of cache->lines[0] does indeed return a pointer to your allocated array of 'lines', and thus yes your example call is in fact the right way to do it.

Remember that the cache->lines is a allocated array of pointers (the second call to `malloc`).  It merely allocates enough space for `2^s * the_size_of_a_pointer`

The rest of the mallocs below that allocate enough space for `E * size_of_a_line`.

So when you dereference the cache pointer (using `->`) and then deference the lines pointer (by using `[0]`) then you end up with a memory pointer to `E` lines.

Then in your function, you can use `lines[0]` to get to the first line, and `lines[E-1]` to get to the last of whatever array of line pointers was passed in (based on the `[]` operator to the `cache->lines` data pointer).